# How long does it take thames river boats to go from Westminster to Kew Gardens?

Tags: uk, london, riverboats

According to the [Thames River Boats](http://wpsa.co.uk/thames-boats/fares.asp), it costs £17 GBP, but I'm not seeing any mention of times.

Comment: It's the slowest and nicest way to Kew Gardens. I highly recommend it for one way (go by boat, return by tube).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While the WPSA website doesn't have a timetable, the [Transport for London website does](https://tfl.gov.uk/river-tour/timetable/westminster-passenger-service-association?FromId=930GWMR&fromText=Westminster%20Pier&toText=Kew%20Pier&ToId=930GKEW). It looks like it takes about an hour and a half.

(For comparison, it would take about 50 minutes by rail - either the District Line or a train from Waterloo. So not *that* much slower...)